# Error caused by Doctrine dependency changes in DoctrineSubscriber of the Oneup/AclBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle, symfony-2.3

I'm using Oneup\AclBundle and after last update I can't save any entity no more.

When I try to save my entity to the Database:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

... I get this error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Oneup\AclBundle\EventListener\DoctrineSubscriber::postPersist() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs given, called in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.php on line 61 and defined in vendor/oneup/acl-bundle/Oneup/AclBundle/EventListener/DoctrineSubscriber.php line 18

I found this change for Oneup/AclBundle:
https://github.com/danez/OneupAclBundle/commit/f3eacf040677019caad73d221a610c73cbd7dd25

Based on this, I tried to change the file vendor/oneup/acl-bundle/Oneup/AclBundle/EventListener/DoctrineSubscriber.php:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

...

class DoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    ...
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        ...

        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $object = new \ReflectionClass($entity);

        ...
    }
}
```

... to:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

...

class DoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    ...

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        ...

        $entity = method_exists($args, 'getObject')? $args->getObject(): $args->getEntity(); // the called method sometimes changes
        $object = new \ReflectionClass($entity);

        ...
    }
}
```

... and like this it works.

How can I manage to get things working again with this update?
I guess I must somehow make a common doctrine EventClass gets fired, not a ORM doctrine EventClass.

Upon update the log for this bundle was:

> - Updating oneup/acl-bundle dev-master (b3c6ddb => fc3fdbc)
>     Checking out fc3fdbcf3547f0e0520ebb7f7f7e86e3a05779d4

Comment: Bundle dev here. What version of doctrine/common are you running? It seems like I got the constraint wrong. According to the [source](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/LifecycleEventArgs.php) the event object inherits from `LifecycleEventArgs` not until version 2.4, which is not optimal, to say the least.

Comment: I'm using version v2.4.1

Comment: Hi @devsheeep, do you need any further info? I'm still stuck on this one... although I temporarily change the file as I said so I can proceed. Maybe I will just revert to a previous version...

Comment: Hej @hiphip. Sorry for the delay, I'm quite busy these days. Could you create me an issue on https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle, I'll try to find some time to tackle this!

Comment: Actually, my error seems the same as this one https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle/issues/7, I'll comment there linking here.

Comment: It is now working, after bundle updates. Check last link for more info please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned error was thrown because of a combination of too narrow inheritance and a too wide defined composer dependency.

For the record: The bug was reported in [oneup/acl-bundle#7](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle/issues/7) and fixed with the commit [d07385b](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle/commit/d07385b8af79b385fdcddb6884a71c8064b265a9). If you run into this error, update the bundle to the new version [v0.9.1](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle/releases/tag/v0.9.1) and `doctrine/orm` to `2.4.2` as mentioned in [the bug report](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupAclBundle/issues/7#issuecomment-36257540).